# Mongodb best schema design for key value pairs indexation

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I experience some difficulties to find an answer to this question by myself :

What is the best way to store Key/Value Pair in a mongo document AND put an index on it in order to perform multi-criteria searches.

I have documents stored in a mongo database which look like that :

```
{
_id:xxxxxxxxxx,
name : "x1",
tags : [
    {key:"color", value:"blue"},
    {key:"size", value:"L"},
    {key:"weight", value:5}
]
}
```

Each key of the "tags" property is unique (I cannot have more than 1 color or size per document) and each key is optionnal (I can have document without "color" specified).

According to the ["Indexes FAQ"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/indexes/), I created an index like this :

```
{
    "tags.key":1, "tags.value":1
}
```

To perform a query against this index I use this query (to return all blue items) :

```
.find({
    tags:{$elemMatch:{"key":"color","value":"blue"}}
})
```

An explain() shows that the query uses the index. Good!

But now, if I want to make a multi-criteria search, I use this query (to return all blue items with an "L" size) :

```
.find({
    $and:[
        {tags:{$elemMatch:{"key":"color","value":"blue"}}},
        {tags:{$elemMatch:{"key":"size","value":"L"}}}
    ]
})
```

This query is working, but the execution plan shows an IXSAN that scans more documents than the number returned :

```
{
"cursor" : "BtreeCursor Keys",
"isMultiKey" : true,
"n" : 22,
"nscannedObjects" : 53,
"nscanned" : 53,
"nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 53,
"nscannedAllPlans" : 109,
"scanAndOrder" : false,
"indexOnly" : false,
"nYields" : 0,
"nChunkSkips" : 0,
"millis" : 2,
"indexBounds" : {
    "tags.key" : [ 
        [ 
            "color", 
            "color"
        ]
    ],
    "tags.value" : [ 
        [ 
            "blue", 
            "blue"
        ]
    ]
},
"server" : "BLABLABLA:27017",
"filterSet" : false,
"stats" : {
    "type" : "PROJECTION",
    "works" : 55,
    "yields" : 0,
    "unyields" : 0,
    "invalidates" : 0,
    "advanced" : 22,
    "needTime" : 0,
    "needFetch" : 0,
    "isEOF" : 1,
    "children" : [ 
        {
            "type" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
            "works" : 55,
            "yields" : 0,
            "unyields" : 0,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "advanced" : 22,
            "needTime" : 31,
            "needFetch" : 0,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "children" : [ 
                {
                    "type" : "FETCH",
                    "works" : 54,
                    "yields" : 0,
                    "unyields" : 0,
                    "invalidates" : 0,
                    "advanced" : 22,
                    "needTime" : 31,
                    "needFetch" : 0,
                    "isEOF" : 1,
                    "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                    "forcedFetches" : 0,
                    "matchTested" : 22,
                    "children" : [ 
                        {
                            "type" : "IXSCAN",
                            "works" : 53,
                            "yields" : 0,
                            "unyields" : 0,
                            "invalidates" : 0,
                            "advanced" : 53,
                            "needTime" : 0,
                            "needFetch" : 0,
                            "isEOF" : 1,
                            "keyPattern" : "{ tags.key: 1.0, tags.value: 1.0 }",
                            "boundsVerbose" : "field #0['tags.key']: [\"color\", \"userid\"], field #1['Keys.v']: [\"4189\", \"4189\"]",
                            "isMultiKey" : 1,
                            "yieldMovedCursor" : 0,
                            "dupsTested" : 53,
                            "dupsDropped" : 0,
                            "seenInvalidated" : 0,
                            "matchTested" : 0,
                            "keysExamined" : 53,
                            "children" : []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
}
```

It seems that only the first $elemMatch is considered in IXSCAN.

So, is there a way to improve this or no?
Either by changing the query, either by changing the design of my document?

Your help is welcome!

Fred

Comment: I could consider that this was covered only a [few questions ago](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24505020/2313887) or is your question actually something other than how the query optimizer chooses an index to use?

Comment: My question is : Do I need to re-think my schema design to have a better execution plan than the one above. I need to have "tags" on my document in order to make kind of "multi-criteria searches" in my collection (where color = 'blue' and size = 'xl' ...etc). I'm looking for a best pratice to fit my need.