# MongoDB Index intersection example?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongo-shell

I am trying to understand why MongoDB fails to use Index intersection as mentioned over [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-intersection/).

I have inserted 10000 documents in `intersection` collection using the below code block:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        for (var k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
            for (var l = 0; l < 10; l++) {
              db.intersection.insert({a:i, b:j, c:k, d:l});
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then created these 3 indexes:
`db.intersection.createIndex({ a })`
`db.intersection.createIndex({ b : 1, c : 1 })`
`db.intersection.createIndex({ d : 1 })`

At this point I was expecting `db.intersection.find({a:1,b:2,d:4})` to use an intersection between the 3 indexes ie. `a_1, b_1_c_1, d_1`

However this isn't the case and I could see that the winning plan uses only one index, `d_1` :

```
"winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "filter" : {
                                "$and" : [
                                        {
                                                "a" : {
                                                        "$eq" : 1
                                                }
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "b" : {
                                                        "$eq" : 2
                                                }
                                        }
                                ]
                        },
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                "keyPattern" : {
                                        "d" : 1
                                },
                                "indexName" : "d_1",
                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                        "d" : [ ]
                                },
                                "isUnique" : false,
                                "isSparse" : false,
                                "isPartial" : false,
                                "indexVersion" : 2,
                                "direction" : "forward",
                                "indexBounds" : {
                                        "d" : [
                                                "[4.0, 4.0]"
                                        ]
                                }
                        }
                },
```

*Sorry I'm unable to post the allPlansExecution since it exceeds the body word limit*

Additionally, winning plan for `db.inter.find({a:1,b:2})` also uses just one index, `b_1_c_1`.

Can someone please provide an explanation for these results?
Also a practical example demonstrating index intersection would be helpful.

Comment: Indeed it's using index intersection. see `filter` part of query plan. Intersection is happening between `a` and `b`

Comment: There are two stages, the 1st is the Input Stage `IXSCAN` which uses only the `d_1` index and later on a `FETCH` stage is carried out. There's no other index involved here.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3071?focusedCommentId=508454&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-508454) jira ticket on information about index intersection:

> The query optimizer may select index intersection plans when the
>   following conditions hold:
>
> 1. Most of the documents in the relevant collection are disk-resident. The advantage of index intersection is that it can avoid fetching
>      complete documents when the size of the intersection is small. If the
>      documents are already in memory, there is nothing to gain by avoiding
>      fetches.
> 2. The query predicates are single point intervals, rather than range predicates or a set of intervals. Queries over single point intervals
>      return documents sorted by disk location, which allows the optimizer
>      to select plans that compute the intersection in a non-blocking
>      fashion. This is generally faster than the alternative mode of
>      computing the intersection, which is to build a hash table with the
>      results from one index, and then probe it with the results from the
>      second index.
> 3. Neither of the indices to be intersected are highly selective. If one of the indices is selective then the optimizer will choose a plan
>      which simply scans this selective index.
> 4. The size of the intersection is small relative to the number of index keys scanned by either single-index solution. In this case the
>      query executor can look at a smaller set of documents using index
>      intersection, potentially allowing us to reap the benefits of fewer
>      fetches from disk.

Apparently, mongodb can do better in most cases without using an index and it chooses to reject the intersection plan. It would be difficult to come up with an example which ensures that mongodb will use intersection.

For your example, if you see the rejectedPlans for the below query:

```
db.intersection.explain().find({a:1,b:2,d:4});
```

You'll find this as one of the plans (mongodb 3.4):

```
{
    "stage" : "FETCH",
    "filter" : {
        "$and" : [
            {
                "d" : {
                    "$eq" : 4
                }
            },
            {
                "a" : {
                    "$eq" : 1
                }
            },
            {
                "b" : {
                    "$eq" : 2
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "inputStage" : {
        "stage" : "AND_SORTED",
        "inputStages" : [
            {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "d" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "d_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "d" : [ ]
                },
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "d" : [
                        "[4.0, 4.0]"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "a" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "a_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "a" : [ ]
                },
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "a" : [
                        "[1.0, 1.0]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This (AND_SORTED stage) means mongodb did consider index intersection as a possibility, but concluded that d_1 index would perform much better.

Have a look at these answers too: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24505020/5800527) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24786854/5800527).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18670805)

Comment: @amod: Improved the answer based on your review!