# MongoDB Omitting Index Intersection Plan For Ranges

Tags: mongodb

I read [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-intersection/#index-intersection-compound-indexes) and tried to see it in action once. But it didn't work, I was not able to see any index intersection plans in winningPlan or rejectedPlans (mongodb 3.6). When I searched for the problem, I came across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24505020/5800527). So I imitated exactly what was posted there in the question:

Code:

```
for(var i=0;i<100;i++){     
    for(var j=0;j<100;j++){         
       db.t.insert({item:"abc"+i,qty:j})     
    } 
}
```

Indexes:

```
db.t.createIndex({qty:1})
db.t.createIndex({item:1});
```

Query:

```
db.t.explain().find({item:"abc123",qty:{$gt:15}});
```

Result:

```
"winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "filter" : {
                "qty" : {
                    "$gt" : 15
                }
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "item" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "item_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "item" : [ ]
                },
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "item" : [
                        "[\"abc123\", \"abc123\"]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [
            {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "item" : {
                        "$eq" : "abc123"
                    }
                },
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "qty" : 1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "qty_1",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "multiKeyPaths" : {
                        "qty" : [ ]
                    },
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 2,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "qty" : [
                            "(15.0, inf.0]"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
```

I do not see any sign of index intersection attempts by mongodb. However, the below query shows `AND_SORTED` stage in `rejectedPlans`:

```
db.t.explain().find({item:"abc123",qty:15});
```

Did anything change in mongodb that I am not able to find in the documentation? Can someone please help me with what I am missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intersection doesn't work with ranged queries unless it dramatically changed in v3.6. From old https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3071?focusedCommentId=508454&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-508454:

> A: The query optimizer **may** select index intersection plans when the
>   following conditions hold:
>
> - Most of the documents in the relevant collection are disk-resident.
>     The advantage of index intersection is that it can avoid fetching
>     complete documents when the size of the intersection is small. If the
>     documents are already in memory, there is nothing to gain by avoiding
>     fetches.
> - **The query predicates are single point intervals, rather than
>     range predicates or a set of intervals.** Queries over single point
>     intervals return documents sorted by disk location, which allows the
>     optimizer to select plans that compute the intersection in a
>     non-blocking fashion. This is generally faster than the alternative
>     mode of computing the intersection, which is to build a hash table
>     with the results from one index, and then probe it with the results
>     from the second index.
> - Neither of the indices to be intersected are
>     highly selective. If one of the indices is selective then the
>     optimizer will choose a plan which simply scans this selective index.
> - The size of the intersection is small relative to the number of index
>     keys scanned by either single-index solution. In this case the query
>     executor can look at a smaller set of documents using index
>     intersection, potentially allowing us to reap the benefits of fewer
>     fetches from disk.

Comment: I guess the example provided in the documentation should be changed to a single point interval example then!